# Store value from a jform to another

Tags: java, netbeans

I want to store 2 variables and pass them to another jframe

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
city=Combo_box_city.getSelectedItem().toString();
product=Combo_box_products.getSelectedItem().toString();
panel2.setVisible(true);
```

This is how i store the data from the 2 combo_boxes
Now, how should I pass the data in another jframe?

**SOLUTION**

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

new Panel2(Combo_box_city.getSelectedItem().toString(),Combo_box_products.getSelectedItem().toString()).setVisible(true);
dispose();
    }
```

In panel 2:

```
public class Panel2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Panel2
     */
String get_city;String get_product;
    public Panel2(String city,String product) {
get_city=city;
get_product=product;
System.out.print(get_city+get_product);
        initComponents();
this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
setResizable(false);

}
```

And comment all main

Comment: Use static variables to hold the data, you can then access those static variables from your other `jframe`.

Comment: Create an application model using a plain Java getter/setter class and pass an instance of the class to both `JFrames`.